# Error al subir aplicacion web con yarn react vite a hosting compartido cpanel

Tags: reactjs, api, hosting, cpanel, yarn

Por alguna razón no se muestra mi aplicación cuando quiero subirlo a mi dominio, es una aplicación web con react vite donde ocupo un api de Google maps. De forma local funciona sin problemas, pero al subirla me muestra el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi package.json ya agrege el script de homepage con la ruta designada

```
"scripts": {
    "homepage": "https://viajesquality.com/MapsClientPage/",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

asi tengo ordenados mis archivos en react:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después escribí el comando `yarn run build` para crear la carpeta dist y subirla a la ruta del administrador de archivos de mi cpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual tengo entendido debería de funcionar. Espero puedan ayudarme, cualquier comentario se los agradeceré.